# отправка клиентом HTTP-запросов к серверу

Tags: php, json, http, xmlhttprequest

Как написать на php post/get запрос к серверу? В инструкции к API в качестве примера привели следующие строки:

> --- BEGIN ---   POST http://primer.ru/api/Authorization/CreateAuthToken HTTP/1.1
>   Content-Length: 38   Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>   {"Login": "логин","Password": "пароль"}
>   --- END ---

Не понятно что с этим делать. (гуглил..примеров куча, но цельного ответа не нашел, в php очень слаб.)

Планируется в ответ получить код авторизации и использовать его уже в get запросе для авторизации на сервере: `GET api/integration/v1/inn/​<inn>​/kkts?​AuthToken='код авторизации'`
Потом можно get запросом получить нужные мне данные:
`GET api/integration/v1/inn/​<inn>​/kkts`
Ответы предполагаются в формате JSON.

Помогите пожалуйста написать серверный код на php для поставленной задачи.
Спасибо.

Comment: Читайте документацию (http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.curl.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать `CURL` для данной задачи, например

```
function get_info_by_curl($URL, $PostFields)
{
  $CH = curl_init();
  if ($CH === false)
  {
    echo 'Initialization error #'.curl_errno($CH).' ---- '.curl_error($CH);
  }

  curl_setopt($CH, CURLOPT_URL,  $URL);
  curl_setopt($CH, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($CH, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($CH, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($CH, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1);

  curl_setopt($CH, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($CH, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($CH, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $PostFields);

  $Result = curl_exec($CH);
  $CURL_Error = curl_errno($CH);

  if ($CURL_Error > 0)
  {
    echo 'cURL Error: --'.$CURL_Error.'--<br>';
    $RetStr = false;
  }
  else
  {
    $RetStr = $Result;
  }

  curl_close($CH);
  return $RetStr;

}
```

При вызове фунции передаёте ресурс на который должен обращатся запрос, и параметры(если необходимо)

```
$URL = 'Ссылка на ресурс';

$PostFields  = 'params=1&';
$PostFields .= 'params2=2&';
$PostFields .= 'params3=3;

$Response = get_info_by_curl($URL, $PostFields);
print_r($Response);
```